# Eisenbud commutative algebra corollary 10.7

Tags: commutative-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

[image]

The $\leq$ direction is clear to me, but I do not know how the other direction works: I understand all the steps but I do not understand how this proofs anything in terms of dim R.

Comment: This might help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem

Comment: @Laci sorry I do not see it. I see that $R/(x_1,\dots, x_d)$ has dim 0 as it only has 1 prime ideal. But I do not see how this helps.

Comment: For example this implies that the ring is artinian, hence the only maximal ideal is nilpotent.

Comment: Yes, but how dies this implies that dim R $\geq$ d?

Comment: This only implies that there exists  $n$ such that $m^n\subset (x_1,\dots,x_d)$. The dimension part comes from Krull’s theorem which states that a prime ideal $P$ has height $d$ if and only if there exists elements $x_1,\dots,x_d\in R$ such that $P$ is minimal containing them, and for a local ring $\text{ht}(m)=\text{dim}(R)$.

Comment: I do not think that this is what Krulls theorem states: If a prime ideal P is minimal over an ideal generated by d elements it only states that $ht(P) \leq d$

Comment: And it also states that if $\text{ht}(P)=d$ then there exists elements $x_1,\dots,x_n\in R$ such that $P$ is minimal containing them.